# with and without trailing slash

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

What would I make this rule so that you can access it with and without trailing slash?

```
RewriteRule ^members/([^/]+)$ members.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^members/([^/]+)/?$ members.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Just added "/?" at the end to say look for a trailing slash but the ? says it doesn't have to be there.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about this "`mod-rewrite`" you speak of (probably an Apache module?), but that sure looks like a [regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), and I know about those. :-)

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^members/([^/]+)(/|)$ members.php?id=$1 [L]
```

So, to break that into pieces, the `^` means "begins with", "`members/`" means matching exactly that, `([^/]+)` means "1 or more characters that aren't slash, assigning to `$1`", `(/|)` means "slash or empty string, assigning to `$2`", and the `$` part at the end means "the string has to end here".

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to extract the domain name, so I used this:

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www[0-9]*\.)?(.*?)(?:\/.*)?$
```

In my spreadsheet, it looks like this:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(CELL_WITH_URL,"^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www[0-9]*\.)?(.*?)(?:\/.*)?$")
```

Hope that saves someone some time!  Happy REGEXing!